# Ошибка в запросе MYSQL при выборке пользователей

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос к базе данных

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  "rovno"
WHERE
  ("years" BETWEEN 19 AND 60) "message" = 1
ORDER BY
  "rate" DESC
LIMIT 0,20
```

Он выбирает из таблицы столбцы с данными пользователей,у которых открыты ЛС и возраст от 19 до 60 и после сортируются по рейтингу через `ORDER BY DESC`.

Где ошибка в данном запросе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обрамления названия таблиц и полей вы используете двойные кавычки - это не верно, следует использовать обратные (эти кавычки нужны, если у вас имеются названия, совпадающие с зарезервированными ключевыми словами)

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `rovno`
WHERE
  (`years` BETWEEN 19 AND 60) AND `message` = 1
ORDER BY
  `rate` DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Кроме того, в условии `WHERE` не хватает ключевого слова `AND` (а может `OR`?) между условиями `("years" BETWEEN 19 AND 60)` и `"message" = 1`.